# How to convert object to date in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have pandas column like following

```
   January 2014
   February 2014
```

I want to convert it to following format
        201401
        201402
I am doing following

```
   df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date,format= '%Y%B')
```

But,it gives me an error.

Comment: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` should just work

Comment: It does not work. Giving me an error.

Comment: Post raw data, code to read and create your df, what you tried and all errors in your question so this doesn't become a guessing game

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't need the format string, it just works:

```
In [207]:
pd.to_datetime('January 2014')

Out[207]:
Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00')
```

besides your format string is incorrect, it should be `'%B %Y'`:

```
In [209]:
pd.to_datetime('January 2014', format='%B %Y')

Out[209]:
Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00')
```