# format a pandas dataframe column to datatime format

Tags: python, pandas, format

I do have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
date                 city

2-Feb-11              a

22-May-91             b

15-Jul-08             c

8-Feb-16              d
```

The current format of the DisbursementDate column is object.
How can I change it to datetime?

I've tried some things like below code but no sucess.

```
df['DisbursementDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DisbursementDate'], format='%d%b%y')
```

or

```
df['DisbursementDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DisbursementDate'], format='%d%b%y')
```

or

```
df['DisbursementDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DisbursementDate'], format='%-d%b%y')
```

I want to format this column as datetime to then sort it by date.

Comment: Is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693410/how-to-convert-object-to-date-in-pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert object to date in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693410/how-to-convert-object-to-date-in-pandas)